# Vue.js - Use props in single file component script section

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vue and have a really hard time getting it working. I made a single file component for my google maps div:

map.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="map" class="col-100">{{searchArea.radius}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    function updateSearchLocation(latlng) {
        this.searchArea.lat = latlng.lat();
        this.searchArea.long = latlng.lng();
    }

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: false
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
            updateSearchLocation(map.getCenter());
        });
        addMyLocationButton();
        getMyLocation();
    }

    window.initMap = initMap;

    module.exports = {
        props: {
            searchArea: Object
        }
    }
</script>
```

The other functions called here (addMyLocationButton, getMyLocation) are also defined in this file and working. What's not working is accessing the searchArea object within the updateSearchLocation function.

I have a searchArea object in the root of my app:

```
searchArea: {
    lat: null,
    long: null,
    radius: 2500
}
```

It's succesfully passed to this component (I can see it on this component in the vue dev tools). I want to use this map.vue component to update this object because in another component I'm making API calls based on this object.

The map is showing, so initMap is being called. The getMyLocation method gets the current location of the user, and then calls the same updateSearchLocation function.

Loading my map like this:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

put functions into exported object within 'methods' object:

```
module.exports = {
        props: {
            searchArea: Object
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                latlng: whatever
            }
        },       
        methods: {
            updateSearchLocation: function(this.latlng) {..... },
            initMap: function() {.. call updateSearchLocation() as this.updateSearchLocation(this.latlng) ... },
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would I make initMap available to window? So it can be called when the google maps script is loaded. I updated my initial post with how I load the map.

Comment: I think this can help: [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/google-maps-and-vue-js): var App = window.App = new Vue({...});

or even a complete solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/o3ahd45z/